# Azure Disk Encryption (ADE) for AKS cluster node's OS & Data disks

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-disk

I couldn't get clear answer if ADE is supported or not for AKS cluster node's OS & data disks. Has anyone used ADE for AKS node disks? If yes, any reference url/document will be helpful.

Update: As per [this](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/629#issuecomment-573040889) year old thread it seems ADE is not supported for AKS cluster node disks.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT As per my understanding host-based encryption & Azure Disk encryption(ADE) are different. I agree host based encryption is supported by aks cluster but ADE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its Supported as per this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/enable-host-encryption),

> With **host-based encryption**, the data stored on the VM host of your AKS
> agent nodes' VMs is encrypted at rest and flows encrypted to the
> Storage service. This means the temp disks are encrypted at rest with
> platform-managed keys. The cache of **OS and data disks is encrypted** at
> rest with either **platform-managed keys or customer-managed keys**
> depending on the encryption type set on those disks. **By default, when
> using AKS, OS and data disks are encrypted at rest with
> platform-managed keys, meaning that the caches for these disks are
> also by default encrypted at rest with platform-managed keys.**

For Details on how to do `Host-based encryption on Azure Kubernetes Service`, Please follow the Document.

If you want to **Bring Your Own Keys**, then please refer this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disk-customer-managed-keys) .